# Reduce quantitiy from stock in opencart2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am new to `opencart2`. When I order a product from frontend, it doesn't `reduce the quantity` from stock.

But when I update the `order` and mark it as `complete` then it reduces the quantity

I want that the quantity should be reduced at the time of order only. How can I go to this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

It is default functionality of opencart. It only subtract stock only if admin changes order status and that status is selected as `Complete Order Status` from settings. If you want to do so then you have to modify `model/checkout/order.php` file.